# What is an optimal way of blocking unsupported/invalid requests in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, rack

Sample a Rails application running on Heroku. We get a certain pattern of (seemingly DoS) requests each day and I'd like to configure the middleware to handle these fellas, instead of the Rails application firing up to return a `Exception: ActionController::UnknownFormat` or a `Exception: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` for each of these. I feel that is not the best way to handle them.

I implemented a Rack::Attack that looks like so:

```
class Rack::Attack
blocklist('block ip') do |req|
  ['a.b.c.d','w.x.y.z'].include? req.ip
end

blocklist('block corrupt paths') do |req|
    req.path =~ /\w*((\.aspx)|(\.php)|(\.txt)|(\.zip)|(\.tar)|(\.rar)|(\.com)|(\.sql))$/
end

blocklisted_response = lambda do |env|
  # Using 503 because it may make attacker think that they have successfully
  # DOSed the site. Rack::Attack returns 403 for blocklists by default
  [ 503, {}, ['Blocked']]
end end
```

While it did block a certain style of batch-requests that would regularly show up in logs, it still doesn't do the job well. In particular, I see the following style of requests in burst mode made to our application each day:

- //config/AspCms_Config.asp
- /home/favicon.ico
- /3/favicon.ico

Each error request and report is resource-consuming and expensive.

How do I handle these requests better? Does the solution lie in further modifying the regex? Are there other standards I need to read into?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting your app behind something like CloudFlare? Depending on your needs they have a free plan: https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/